# Vim positive lookahead regex

Tags: regex, vim

I am still not so used to the vim regex syntax. I have this code:

```
rename_column :keywords, :textline_two_id_4, :textline_two_id_4
```

I would like to match the last id with a positive lookahead in VIMs regex syntax.

How would you do this?

```
\id@=_\d$
```

This does not work.

This perl syntax works:

```
id(?=_\d$)
```

Edit - the answer:

```
/id\(_\d$\)\@=
```

Can someone explain the syntax?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

If you check the vim help, there is not much to explain: (`:h \@=`)

```
\@=     Matches the preceding atom with zero width. {not in Vi}
        Like "(?=pattern)" in Perl.
        Example             matches
        foo\(bar\)\@=       "foo" in "foobar"
        foo\(bar\)\@=foo    nothing
```

This should match the last id:

```
/id\(_\d$\)\@=
```

save some back slashes with "very magic":

```
/\vid(_\d$)@=
```

actually, it looks more straightforward to use vim's `\zs \ze`:

```
id\ze_\d$
```

Comment: Thanks. Why Do I have to surround the text before \@= with () ?

Comment: @Hendrik without the `()` how can the regex engine know, which part is the Zero-width matching part?

Comment: @Hendrik the parentheses are necessary if the things before the lookahead are a group of atoms. In your case you have three atoms `_`,`\d`,and `$`. So without out the parentheses the lookahead only looks for a `$` which isn't very useful. The parentheses are treated as one atom so you can lookahead for `_\d$`

Comment: where is the documentation for `\zs` and `\ze` ? I don't see anything at http://vimregex.com/#substitute

Comment: @Maslow you are looking for it in wrong place... just open your vim, and `:h \zs`

Comment: <rant> Regex syntax is already awful but vim regex syntax with all the necessary escaping and obscure non standard constructs manages to make things 10 times worse </rant>

Comment: @Kent in my humble opinion very magic is even worse!! because you have to remember which escapings can or cannot be avoided. Its a complete mess

Comment: @AKludges if you cannot say the difference between BRE ERE PCRE, yes, escaping in regex is confusing. If you have to work with regex often, I suggest learning it. otherwise, ask Q here or google, you can solve your problem too. good luck.