# and not search pattern

Tags: regex, vim

I created `vim` search pattern to find bad status codes:

```
   / [45][0-9][0-9]
```

It can find `504` or `499` or `404` (space before and after each number)

But I don't want it to find `404`. How to change my search pattern to make it skip `404`?

Comment: With the given information there's no way for us to create a regex matching your needs. What kind of status codes do you want to match?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a negative look-ahead for that number:

```
/\(.*404\)\@![45]\d\{2\}
```

**UPDATE**: Thanks to [Karoly Horvath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/650405/karoly-horvath) to point out that this `regex` could fail with some numbers in the same line. Much better:

```
/\(404\)\@![45]\d\{2\}
```

---

Another way with a negative look-behind after the match:

```
/[45]\d\{2\}\(404\)\@<!
```

Comment: Does vim support lookahead in regexes? Isn't that a POSIX engine?

Comment: @TimPietzcker It does.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Yes. It supports them. `Vim` regex flavour is very powerfull. You can look at it with `:help regex`

Comment: don't use `.*`, that prevents any matches in a line which contains 404.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: You are right, but what passed my test is that I put the `404` as the first number, like: `one 404 two 504`. And it matches the `504`, but not in `one 504 two 404`.

Comment: @Birei with required spaces before and after status codes: `/ [45]\d\{2\} \( 404 \)\@<!`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Nothing at all. I can rid of it. Sorry that I didn't understand you the first time :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
5[0-9][0-9]|4[1-9][0-9]|40[0-35-9]
```

The old-school pattern is:

- 5 followed by any two digits, OR:
- 4 not followed by zero, and then any digit, OR:
- 40 not followed by 4.

I hope you don't have other black-listed codes, because this will get ugly very quickly.

Comment: I'm probably wrong about the lookahead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391665/vim-positive-lookahead-regex . I'll remove that comment.