# Increment numbers between delimiters in vim

Tags: regex, vim, replace

My question is about a very specific search and replace pattern, but I hope to find answers for the more general case. I am currently working on some LaTeX slides with allot of overlays and I need to increment certain integers by one or more. A sample text:

```
\only<1,5-7,9>{hello 11}
```

In short, the **only** command only shows *hello 11* on slide number 1, 5 through 7 and 9. After inserting a slide at position 2, I need all slides above slide 2 to increment. This is what I came up with:

```
:.,$s/\d\+/\=str2float(submatch(0))>2?submatch(0)+1:submatch(0)/g
```

From the current line to the end of the file, it increments **all** integers above 2 by 1. This means that 11 is also incremented, which is not what I want:

```
\only<1,6-8,10>{hello 12}
```

**Q1**: How can I only match and increment the integers between the delimiters '<' and '>'?

---

Ultimately, I would like to be able to *refine* search patterns incrementally by specifying a pattern and apply another pattern to the result. For instance I first match the text between delimiters from the given example text.

```
/<[^<>]*>
```

which would highlight the text I have quoted:

```
\only"<1,5-7,9>"{hello 11}
```

And now apply my original solution to increment the numbers between the delimiters. I can compare what I would like to do with chaining **grep** commands together in a shell with the pipe symbol, refining the result with each new grep command.

**Q2:** Is this *chaining* of vim search patterns possible?

---

**Update:** The solution of Floris comes very close. Indeed it solves the original question, but I failed to mention all requirements. They are:

```
- The delimiters are guaranteed to be on one line, e.g., <1,5-7,9>.
- Multiple delimited parts can be on one line, e.g.:
   hello 11\only<1,6-7,9>{hello 11}\only<1,6-7,9>{hello 11}
```

The second requirement fails, as the solution currently returns:

```
hello 12\only<1,7-8,10>{hello 12}\only<1,7-8,10>{hello 11}
```

It only ignores integers after the last occurrence of '>'. I would like the result to be:

```
hello 11\only<1,7-8,10>{hello 11}\only<1,7-8,10>{hello 11}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You are really trying to make this hard aren't you?!... I think I may be able to solve it if there are only commas, hyphens and digits in between the `<>`, but can't test right now and would like confirmation before I make another "nearly" answer...

Comment: I try :) I suppose instead of numbers between < and >, you could view it as numbers enclosed by characters [<>,-].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to apply a search-and-replace (with an expression that can evaluate the conditional!) only at certain places (i.e. inside the `<...>` parts).

That's difficult, because you either need to:

- carefully specify the match conditions with *lookahead* and *lookbehind* (as the other answers have attempted), or
- match on the `<...>`, and perform another substitution inside, which Vim doesn't allow (recursive *sub-replace-expression* (`\=...`) isn't possible)

The new version 1.30 of my [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602) can handle this:

First, search for the `<...>` locations:

```
/<[^>]\+>
```

Then, formulate a special substitution that is applied only within the search results:

```
:%SubstituteInSearch/\d\+/\=submatch(0) > 2 ? submatch(0) + 1 : submatch(0)/g
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a `lookahead` construct - I *think* it is as follows:

```
:.,$s/[0-9]\+\(.*>\)\@=/\=str2float(submatch(0))>2?submatch(0)+1:submatch(0)/g
```

The thing I added is

```
\(.*>\)\@=
```

This is a "positive lookahead", a zero-width assertion that says

> the thing before this must be followed by any number of characters followed by close bracket

You can find a bit more information about the syntax in vim help, or https://stackoverflow.com/a/18391881/1967396 (which is where I got it from).

Running the above, I did get

```
\only<1,6-8,10>{hello 11}
```

as the output - which is what I think you wanted.

Note: I tested this in `vim` on the Mac. It has been known to behave slightly differently than the linux version (well, I'm extrapolating from the `sed` differences, I don't actually *know* that `vim` is different too...) . If this isn't working, it should be jolly close.

Comment: It truly comes very close. There is a case where it fails though, which is my bad, because I didn't mention it in my question. Although the delimiters are located on the same line, there can be multiple delimited parts on the line. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that `\only<....` will appear on a line of it's own, you can simply

```
:.,$g/\\only<\d/s/\d\+/\=str2float(submatch(0))>2?submatch(0)+1:submatch(0)/g
```

Which is, the `:global` command (`:.,$g/\\only<\d/`) used to filter the targeted lines, and then your "magic" subsitution unaltered :)

Comment: I think the problem is that the substitution continues with the number after `hello`. You need a `lookaround` expression ("digit in between `<` and `>`), and I'm not sure that vim's regex supports it?

Comment: @Floris ah... I expect the post to show the intended outcome... :{

Comment: that would have been reasonable; but he _did_ say "This means that 11 is also incremented, which is not what I want".

Answer (score 0):

The question about regex is of course relevant, but concerning your too numerous overlays, maybe you should consider using names instead of numbers: a solution is available on Tex-Latex at:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34458/reference-overlay-numbers-with-names?rq=1