# Vim Syntax Highlighting: highlight `self` python keyword with regex

Tags: python, regex, vim, vi, macvim

I am trying to customize the syntax highlighting for python in vim. I want to highlight the keyword `self` but only when it is followed by a `.`. Here is the code I came up with:

```
syn match   pythonBoolean     "\(\Wself\)\%(\.\)"
```

Unfortunately, the `.` is also highlighted though I use a non capturing group `\%(\.\)`.

Any idea?

Comment: have your tried \v at the beginning to activate very magic

Comment: I tried it, it does't change a thing. From my understanding, `\v` allows to avoid escaping special characters like parentheses, etc.

Comment: But `self` is not a keyword in python.

Comment: @aragaer you're right, but whether it is a keyword or not doesn't change the problem at hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the **lookaround**:

```
:syn match pythonBoolean "\(\W\|^\)\zsself\ze\."
```

or

```
:syn match pythonBoolean "\(\W\|^\)\@<=self\(\.\)\@="
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Building on @Meninx's answer, I added this to my `.vimrc`:

```
augroup PythonCustomization
  " highlight python self, when followed by a comma, a period or a parenth
   :autocmd FileType python syn match pythonStatement "\(\W\|^\)\@<=self\([\.,)]\)\@="
augroup END
```

**Note 1**: that in addition to what the op asked, it will also highlight when `self` is followed by a comma or a closing parenthesis.

**Note 2**: instead of using `pythonBoolean`, this highlights `self` using `pythonStatement` (personal preference). You can use other highlight-groups (run `:syn` with a python file open to see what's available)

Answer (score 1):

How about using [lookbehinds and lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)? A valid regex for an occurence of self preceded by any non-word character `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` and followed by `.` in common regex syntax is: `(?<=\W)(self)(?=\.)`

For vim regex take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391665/vim-positive-lookahead-regex), and, if you need more help, check [this page](https://www.inputoutput.io/lookbehind-lookahead-regex-in-vim/) out.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to lookbehind and lookahead, which tend to slow down vim:

```
syn match pythonBoolean "\<self\ze\."
```

Or, in case you want to highlight all objects:

```
syn match pythonBoolean "\<\w\+\ze\."
```